# How to generate MD5 fingerprint using macbook 10.5.8 for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I want to generate `MD5 Fingerprint` for using `GoogleMap` in Android. But I am using `Macbook 10.5.8` and `Eclipse Indigo`.

Any suggestion will be appreciate...

Comment: I just want to know one more thing is that I am not having debug.keystore file in .android folder.So is this the reason because of which i am not able to generate MD5 fingerprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for my question is we can create MD5 fingerprint for MAC in a usual way i.e. by using the following command
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android

One important thing about MAC is .android folder is hidden.To make that folder visible we have use command Command+Shift+G.

Problem with me is I have installed fresh eclipse and I had not run a single project so the debug.keystore file was not generated.So it is giving me an error of file not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the process to generate MD5 fingerprint.
[Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Comment: If you have already created a key for signing your app then you can find out the md5 fingerprint by `keytool -list -alias key -keystore "path to .keystore" -storepass android -keypass android` . change the parameters as per your key alias

Comment: Thanks for the replay but I had already gone through that site it works for windows but i am using macbook for which it is not working..

Comment: The command in the site is not working for mac it shows me an error  "-bash: keytool.exe: command not found"

Comment: dont use keytool.exe just use keytool
`keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: I did that also but still I am not able to generate MD5 fingerprient.

Comment: Are you using the right key, alias and password? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11222/discussion-between-akshay-and-tarun-maheshwari)